# Doubt about the role of "equivalence class of functions" in this Least Square example.

Tags: functional-analysis, least-squares, regression-analysis

I am dealing with a proof from De Boor (1972) about least square approximations using splines. 
Suppose we have a set of data and we want to estimate the least square approximation.
Let $ \$ $ be a finite dimensional linear space of functions, we seek a *best approximation from $\$$ to 'g' with respect to the norm $||\cdot||_2 $*.
This is we want to find $f^*\in\$$ such that:
$\forall f \in \$$ $$||'g'-f^*||_2=min_{f\in\$}||'g'-f||_2$$
The author then says:

> We have put *g* in quotes here because we do not knot *g*. 
>   Instead we intend to use the approximate value $g_i$ whenever the value $g(x_i)$ is called for. In effect *'g'* is an equivalence class of functions.

I am not familiar with the concept of "equivalence class of functions" and don't really understand what are the consequences of *'g'* being such. 
Obviously we ignore the real function *'g'* due to the presence of some error term, but I am lost with the mathematical terminology.

Any hint or suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think what the author means is simply the usual "equivalence" of functions under the $L^2$ norm, that is we say $f,g\in L^2$ are *equivalent* if $\Vert f-g \Vert_2 = 0$, the equivalence class of a function is simply the set of functions with are equivalent to it. Note that $\Vert f-g \Vert_2 = 0$ iff $\int \vert f(x)-g(x) \vert dx = 0$, this may happen without the functions $f,g$ being truely equal, meaning $f(x) = g(x)$ for all $x$, for example, if I take a Reimann integrable function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and change it at one point, it is still equivalent to $f$.

This is relevant in this case since to approximate a function $g$, it doesn't matter which of the functions of the equivalence class $'g'$ you arppoximate.